# Round up instead of down

Tags: kotlin, rounding

In the Kotlin programming language, .toInt() rounds down. how do I round up instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ceil(double x)` to round any double to a higher value.

Or use `roundToInt`.

```
fun main() {
    val x = 10.55f
 
    val y: Int = x.roundToInt()
    println("y = $y")            // y = 11
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use .ceil

```
math.ceil(x).toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. By using decimal format,

   ```
   fun Double.ceilRound():Int{
    return DecimalFormat("#").apply {
        roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    }.format(this).toInt()
   }
   ```

2. `fun Double.roundCeil():Int = ceil(this).toInt()`

   ```
    fun main() {
    val a = 5.35
    println(a.ceilRound()) //6
    println(a.roundCeil()) //6
    val b = 5.75
    println(b.ceilRound()) //6
    println(b.roundCeil()) //6
    }
   ```